# React + Express session variable wont persist

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session

**index.js**

```
if (result) {
   console.log("SESSION1: ", req.session)
   req.session.token = await createAuth(row[0]["user_id"]);
   console.log("SESSION2: ", req.session)
   console.log("logged in!", req.session.token)
   res.send(true);
   return
}

...

app.get("/api/categories", async function(req, res){
    console.log("SESSION5: ", req.session)
    let token = req.session.token;
    console.log("REQUESTING CATEGORIES: ", token)

    ...
});
```

The first part is taken from my /login and prints out

```
SESSION1:  Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
SESSION2:  Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  token: 'd90b4976-4c12-4605-80e7-770df1e5e33dAT'
}

logged in! d90b4976-4c12-4605-80e7-770df1e5e33dAT
```

However once I make a request like so in react

```
    fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/categories", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Token": 1234,
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(async resp => {
      resp = await resp.json()
    })
    .then(categoriesResp => {
      console.log("CATEGORIES: ", categoriesResp)
      this.setState({
        categories: categoriesResp
      })
    });
```

The session token is undefined and I get

```
SESSION5:  Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

So the token session variable is not persisting across the requests here.
I checked similar questions and tried

- setting cookie: {secure: false}
- Making sure my server wasnt restarting
  However none of these things had any effect and are producing the same problem.
  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Express JS but I had faced a similar issue working on the project with React Axios and Django & Django Rest Framework.

I just went through the fetch API I found that you have to add 

fetch('https://example.com:1234/users', {
  credentials: 'include'
})

and also in the express side, I guess you have to make CORS related changes. The below article might help. 

https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Go to the HTTP Sessions Over CORS section in the article.

Comment: @AashayAmballi Tried doing this and has not changed anything, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Setting cors to

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
}));
```

and using

```
credentials: true
```

as suggested by @AashayAmballi actually worked, just had to make sure I was including it in all of my requests including the initial login